# Resize target layer in perspective tracking

Tags: after-effects, tracking

I created a perspective corner pin tracker in After Effects. I selected a target, and applied it.
Unfortunately, the target is not of the same aspect ratio as the virtual rectangle that I tracked.Therefore, it is horizontally scaled.
What I want to do, is correct the scaling and position, within the corners.
When I resize the target layer, init expands beyond the corners.Which makes sense, but it it not the sense I'm looking for.
What would be my strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-comp the replacement layer (using the option to keep all the settings in the outer comp), and match the aspect ratio of the pre-comp to the rectangle you're tracking. Then adjust the replacement layer so that it fills the comp as you wish.